# Getting invalig use of non static data member error in c++

Tags: c++, non-static

Whats wrong with the code below even if I have used the variable file_op properly as non static variable and also declared properly I am getting below error....

```
class ILV_file_operations: public ILV_command
{
private:
    /**
     * \copydoc ILV_command::ILV_command_request
     */
    class Request: public ILV_command_request<ILV_file_operations>
    {
        friend class ILV_file_operations;
        // New format parameters
        uint32_t file_op;
        std::string file_path;
        std::string file_read_data;
        uint8_t request_status; //!<  Response status
    public:
        explicit Request(ILV_file_operations& parent_ref);
        ~Request();

        /**
         * \brief This is method to read the parameters received in the request.
         * \return
         * \arg \c Length: Length of the request data read
         */
        uint32_t read_params();
    };

    class Response: public ILV_command_response<ILV_file_operations>
    {
        friend class ILV_file_operations;
        //New parameter
        std::list<Sub_ILV> param_ILV; ///< Parameter ILV

        // Old format parameters
        std::string file_write_data; ///< Serial number
        uint8_t response_status; //!<  Response status
    public:
        explicit Response(ILV_file_operations& parent_ref);
        ~Response();

        /**
         * \brief This is method to calculate the length of the response to be sent.
         * \return
         * \arg \c Length: Length of the response data
         */
        uint32_t calculate_length();
        /**
         * \brief This is method to write the parameters in the response.
         * \return
         * \arg \c Length: Length of the response data written
         */
        uint32_t write_params();
    };

    Response resp_data; ///< Response data object
    Request req_data; ///< Request data object

public:

    /**
     * \copydoc ILV_command::ILV_command
     */
    explicit ILV_file_operations(boost::shared_ptr<Protocol>& prtcl);
    /**
     */
    virtual ~ILV_file_operations();

    void process();
    uint32_t read_packet();
    uint32_t write_packet();
};


uint32_t ILV_file_operations::Response::write_params()
{
    uint32_t ret_val = 0;

    if (((int)req_data.file_op) == ((int)file_operation_type::write))
    {
        ret_val += parent.cmd_prot->write_string(file_write_data);
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

Error :

```
| Compiling core_app/src-libs/libCommand_manager/src/ILV_commands/ILV_file_operations.cpp ...
| In file included from core_app/src-libs/libCommand_manager/src/ILV_commands/ILV_file_operations.cpp:11:0:
| ../include/ILV_commands/ILV_file_operations.h: In member function 'virtual uint32_t Dist_cmd_processor::ILV_file_operations::Response::write_params()':
| ../include/ILV_commands/ILV_file_operations.h:82:13: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Dist_cmd_processor::ILV_file_operations::req_data'
|      Request req_data; ///< Request data object
|              ^
| /home/sagar/morpho/MASigma_Firmware_REV_1.0.10/src-ma5g/core_app/src-libs/libCommand_manager/src/ILV_commands/ILV_file_operations.cpp:84:15: error: from this location
|      if (((int)req_data.file_op) == ((int)file_operation_type::write))
|                ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method `write_params` is a member of the class `ILV_file_operations::Response`, but it tries to access a non-static member variable of the class `ILV_file_operations` without an object.
First, you would either need an object of the class `ILV_file_operations` to access its members, or the member would have to be `static`.
But then you could still not access the member variables because they are `private`, and your inner classes don't get automatic access to the member variables of their outer class.